# Base entity common to all tables in EF Core 3.0

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I would like to use a base entity common to all entities as every table should have ad ID, InsertDate and LastModifiedDate.

As per documentation I should create a BaseEntity abstract class and every entity should inheritance from this.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime? InsertDateTime { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Everything was ok until I started adding relations. Now after relations with foreign keys has been added the Migration is creating only one big table called BaseEntity with Discriminators but the abstract base entity should only be used to inheritance common properties.

I have read [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance) that there are 3 type of inheritance but in EF Core 3.0 only TPH is available. Seeing examples on the web with abstract base class aren't having this problems.

I was wondering If I am missing something in my implementation if you guys please help me find out.

Comment: Did you declare a Navigaion property of type BaseEntity?  If you do, BaseEntity becomes an Entity and gets its own table, and you shouldn't do that.  Also a Navigation property of type BaseEntity has terrible code smell.

Comment: I have navigation properties of derived types from BaseEntity but not directly of type BaseEntity. For instance, I have a Class A extended from BaseEntity and have navigation properties of type A. Is that the problem ?

Comment: That should be fine.  Try to simplify the model and produce a simple stand-alone repro and post that in your question.

Comment: I find out the problem. It is happening when I am using Fluent API to set default values for InsertDateTime and LastModifiedDateTime as follows:

`modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().Property(x => x.DateTimeInserimento).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");`

`modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().Property(x => x.DateTimeUltimaModifica).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");`

But I need this db settings to auto-generate this values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>()
```

declares BaseEntity as a database entity.  Instead configure all the subtypes.  Since they are mapped to seperate tables, they need seperate configuration.  EG

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Ignore<BaseEntity>();


    foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if (et.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)))
        {
            et.FindProperty("InsertDateTime").SetDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
            et.FindProperty("InsertDateTime").ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAdd;

            et.FindProperty("LastModifiedDateTime").SetDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
            et.FindProperty("LastModifiedDateTime").ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate;
        }

    }
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Note, that this won't *cause* the `LastModifiedDateTime` to be updated for every change.  That would require a trigger or an interceptor of some kind in EF.

Comment: Yes, exactly! It works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Now I will work on update of LastModifiedDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative.

```
    public abstract class BaseEntityWithUpdatedAndRowVersion
{
    [Display(Name = "Updated By", Description = "User who last updated this meeting.")]
    [Editable(false)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Updated", Description = "Date and time this row was last updated.")]
    [Editable(false)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SQL Server Timestamp", ShortName = "RowVersion", Description = "Internal SQL Server row version stamp.")]
    [Timestamp]
    [Editable(false)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And its abstract configuration:

```
    internal abstract class BaseEntityWithUpdatedAndRowVersionConfiguration <TBase> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TBase> 
    where TBase: BaseEntityWithUpdatedAndRowVersion
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBase> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedDateTime)
            .HasColumnType("datetimeoffset(0)")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(sysdatetimeoffset())");

        entity.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

Here's a concrete class using the base entity.

```
    public partial class Invitation: BaseEntityWithUpdatedAndRowVersion, IValidatableObject
{
    [Display(Name = "Paper", Description = "Paper being invited.")]
    [Required]
    public int PaperId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Registration Fee Waived?", ShortName = "Fee Waived?", 
        Description = "Is the registration fee completely waived for this author?")]
    [Required]
    public bool IsRegistrationFeeFullyWaived { get; set; }
}
```

And its configuration code, calling the base configuration:

```
    internal class InvitationConfiguration : BaseEntityWithUpdatedAndRowVersionConfiguration<Invitation>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Invitation> entity)
    {
        base.Configure(entity);

        entity.HasKey(e => e.PaperId);
        entity.ToTable("Invitations", "Offerings");
        entity.Property(e => e.PaperId).ValueGeneratedNever();
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Paper)
            .WithOne(p => p.Invitation)
            .HasForeignKey<Invitation>(d => d.PaperId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .HasConstraintName("Invitations_FK_IsFor_Paper");
    }
}
```

Finally, this addition to the db context handles the updated by and updated date/time.

```
    public partial class ConferenceDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ConferenceUser, ConferenceRole, int>
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AssignUpdatedByAndTime();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        AssignUpdatedByAndTime();
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AssignUpdatedByAndTime();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AssignUpdatedByAndTime();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Globalization", "CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters", Justification = "App is not being globalized.")]
    private void AssignUpdatedByAndTime()
    {
        //Get changed entities (added or modified).
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var changedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
            .ToList();

        //Assign UpdatedDateTime and UpdatedBy properties if they exist.
        AssignUpdatedByUserAndTime(changedEntities);
    }

    #region AssignUpdated
    /// <summary>Assign updated-by & updated-when to any entity containing those attributes, including general category parent entities.</summary>
    private void AssignUpdatedByUserAndTime(List<EntityEntry> changedEntities)
    {
        foreach (EntityEntry entityEntry in changedEntities)
        {
            //Some subcategory entities have the updated date/by attributes in the parent entity.
            EntityEntry parentEntry = null;
            string entityTypeName = entityEntry.Metadata.Name;  //Full class name, e.g., ConferenceEF.Models.Meeting
            entityTypeName = entityTypeName.Split('.').Last();
            switch (entityTypeName)
            {
                case "Paper":
                case "FlashPresentation":
                case "Break":
                    parentEntry = entityEntry.Reference(nameof(SessionItem)).TargetEntry;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            AssignUpdatedByUserAndTime(parentEntry ?? entityEntry);
        }
    }

    private void AssignUpdatedByUserAndTime(EntityEntry entityEntry)
    {
        if (entityEntry.Entity is BaseEntityWithUpdatedAndRowVersion
            || entityEntry.Entity is PaperRating)
        {
            PropertyEntry updatedDateTime = entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDateTime");
            DateTimeOffset? currentValue = (DateTimeOffset?)updatedDateTime.CurrentValue;
            //Avoid possible loops by only updating time when it has changed by at least 1 minute.
            //Is this necessary?
            if (!currentValue.HasValue || currentValue < DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-1))
                updatedDateTime.CurrentValue = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            if (entityEntry.Properties.Any(p => p.Metadata.Name == "UpdatedBy"))
            {
                PropertyEntry updatedBy = entityEntry.Property("UpdatedBy");
                string newValue = CurrentUserName;  //ClaimsPrincipal.Current?.Identity?.Name;
                if (newValue == null && !updatedBy.Metadata.IsColumnNullable())
                    newValue = string.Empty;
                if (updatedBy.CurrentValue?.ToString() != newValue)
                    updatedBy.CurrentValue = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion AssignUpdated
}
```

Comment: Thank you pjs, I will try it!